# Vue 3 - Bootstrap Rollup Failure

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-vue, vite

I'm new Vue, I don't understand this error from installing bootstrap-vue-3

Install commands:

```
npm i --save bootstrap bootstrap-vue-3
```

Configuration [`main.js`]:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css'

createApp(App)
    .use(BootstrapVue3)
    .mount('#app')
```

Errors:

> Rollup failed to resolve import "bootstrap/js/dist/carousel" from "node_modules/bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.es.js".
>
> This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
> If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to `rollupInputOptions.external`

This is a new project -- nothing added aside from default stuff and bootstrap.

Comment: **bootstrap-vue-3** is still in alpha (and requires Bootstrap v5, by the way) so I would not recommend using it in production. You may want to consider using Quasar instead.

Comment: @Stove I can't reproduce that error ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-bootstrapvue3-vite-starter?file=src%2Fmain.js)). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?